# What is the correct way to get the full size of an HTML element

Tags: jquery

In HTML, the actual height of an element is

actualheight = height + top border + top margin + top padding + bottom margin + bottom border + bottom padding.

Is there a way to get this in JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crap you said **height**, not width, I'll leave my width answer here for reference anyway.
[This page](http://api.jquery.com/height/) explains how to do it with height.

`.outerWidth()` - Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, **including padding and border**.

`.innerWidth()` - Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, **including padding but not border**.

`.width()` - Get the **current computed width** for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: To add to this, `.outerWidth(true)` also includes any offset by **margin** into the calculation. So, in technicality, you actually have `.width()`, `.innerWidth()`, `.outerWidth()`, and `.outerWidth(true)`, which takes all of the dimensioning elements of the CSS box model into account.